# Make a bootstrap selection list transparent

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu

Is it possible to make a standard selection list with transparent background? Please see two example. I know its possible to build a "custom" selection lists and make it transparent background, but is it possible to use a select element?

**HTML - using standard select list with Bootstrap form-group and form-control with custom country (I do not know how to do this select list transparent)**

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control form-control-lg countrylist">
                <option selected>Choose...</option>
                <option>Nigeria</option>
                <option>Sweden</option>
                <option>Poland</option>
                <option>Spain</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

**HTML - Using li, a and ul tags to build a custom selection list.**

```
<li class="dropdown nav-item">
    <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link js-scroll-trigger">Clientes</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#">2ª via do boleto </a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#">Atendimento </a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#">Seja um revendedor </a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#"> Depoimentos </a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#">2ª via do boleto </a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#">Atendimento </a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#">Seja um revendedor </a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

**CSS**

```
.countrylist .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried, in the CSS, using `background:` rather than `background-color`? I do think the standard Bootstrap styling uses `background` and so altering `background-color:` may not change much. You could also try in the CSS giving the background an RGBA color and making it transparent that way? Or semi transparent etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 & 5 have a `.bg-transparent` class which you should be able to add to the `.dropdown-menu` element to set the background to transparent (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/background/).

ie.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu bg-transparent">
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#">2ª via do boleto </a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#">Atendimento </a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#">Seja um revendedor </a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#"> Depoimentos </a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#">2ª via do boleto </a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#">Atendimento </a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#">Seja um revendedor </a></li>
    </ul>
```

Assuming you haven't altered the sass `$enable-important-utilities` var all background classes should already have `!important` & should override the default `.dropdown-menu` CSS.

You might also want to use the `dropdown-menu-dark|light` classes along with the background classes to change up the dropdown styles.